# Tomcat6 ignores logging.properties partially

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat6, java.util.logging

I'm using Tomcat 6, and this is my logging.properties:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=FINE

org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.level = OFF

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ALL
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = mylog.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

On the one hand, Tomcat seems to read this file, as it correctly saves the logfiles with the prefix "mylog" and prints only messages with log-level `FINE` and above. On the other hand, it keeps on writing log messages like this:

```
Jun 8, 2010 9:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Error writing messages
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
```

I actually wanted to suppress all log messages from this class, as they flood my logfile, and the error is irrelevant for me. So why is the following line ignored?

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.level = OFF
```

Is there any other way to suppress the log output of this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext` is not the name of the logger used in ApplicationContext, it uses the log of a composite: the `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`'s log.

--edit:
Maybe it's because they're context loggers. Then they need to be configured differently

something like

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = \
```

I've not done that before, I've never used tomcat's logging facilities, and there is not much [info](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Logging_Tutorial) to find

Comment: I changed the line to

org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.level = OFF

but it still has the same log-output as before.

Comment: Setting  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.level = OFF did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think [Redlab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299787/redlab)'s on the right track - notice that the root of the logger name is `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase`, not `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext`. The method `org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.logName()` controls the logger name and it explicitly starts with `ContainerBase.class.getName()`. Just to clarify, `StandardContext` extends `ContainerBase`.