# How to disable org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log?

Tags: logging, tomcat6, applicationcontext

I am using timcat 6.0 and there are a lot of log like as below, I want to disable it, how can I config file logging.properties?

```
....
2017/05/29 2:06:22 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Info: Loading Spring root WebApplicationContext
....
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the line in logging.properties?

from:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
```

to:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = ERROR
```

Comment: The same result. do you have any other idea? I need to show error message but they are scrolled out...

Comment: "scrolled out"? If you want to disable the logs on your console, you may have to change ConsoleHandler log level from `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE` to `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ERROR`.

Comment: Tried to set to ERROR, same result.

Comment: Ah, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001684/tomcat6-ignores-logging-properties-partially ?